# Why is my internal encoding ISO-8859-1 when I have specified utf-8 in my php.ini file?

Tags: php, unicode, localization

In my php.ini file, I have included `mbstring.internal_encoding = "UTF-8"`.  (I have tried with or without double quotes, capitalized or not.)

Yet when I run `echo "current internal encoding: ".mb_internal_encoding();`, I still get ISO-8859-1.

Why is this, and is there anything I can do in the php.ini file to set internal encoding once and for all?

I'm using WAMPserver on a WinXP laptop.

Comment: When you change the php.ini file are you restarting Apache?

Comment: Yes - I have shut down WAMP, and I have even shut down the computer.

Comment: I've just tested on my server and making that change did affect the output from `mb_internal_encoding()`. Make sure you are editing the right php.ini file by left clicking the tray icon and selecting PHP -> php.ini.

Comment: @spencerw - I'll be damned, I found 2 `php.ini` files under `C:\wamp\bin`, one under php and the other under apache.  I was modifying the wrong one.  If you want to write a 1-sentence answer I'll select it.  And thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments this is because there are usually at least two php.ini files: one for the command line version and one for the Apache plugin. You need to make sure you edit the right one.

This is not an uncommon problem and I've certainly been bitten by it before.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure to override default_charset of yours php.ini use this way, use ini_set('default_charset', 'Your Charset');

put on each php file this piece of code at the beginning...

example: index.php

```
<?php
  $server_root = realpath($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]);
  $config_serv = "$server_root/php/config.php";
  include("$config_serv");
?>
```

then create a folder "php" inside your root server and put this file... this piece of code serves latin1 overriding utf-8...

config.php

```
<?php
  ##########################################################################
  # Server Directive - Override default_charset utf-8 to latin1 in php.ini #
  ##########################################################################
  @ini_set('default_charset', 'ISO-8859-1');
?>
```

or this other one... this piece of code serves utf-8 overriding latin1...
Use the first or the second according to your needs...

config.php

```
<?php
  ##########################################################################
  # Server Directive - Override default_charset latin1 to utf-8 in php.ini #
  ##########################################################################
  @ini_set('default_charset', 'UTF-8');
?>
```