# WAMPserver - why is the stack installed with 2 php.ini files?

Tags: php, apache, wamp, wampserver

I'm a beginner programmer, and I'm learning to program a web app using WampServer.  Recently I have tried to modify the internal encoding setting in the `php.ini` file, and I discovered that there are 2 or them.  One is under `wamp\bin\php\php5.3.0` and the other one is under `wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.11\bin`.  It turns out the 2nd one is the one that governs the behavior of php when I run my program.

So why are there 2 of those files, and what is their respective function?

Thanks,

JDelage

Comment: Guessing here - one is for the command line execution, one is for PHP inside Apache. You can check the locations of php.ini files via `php -i` (for the CLI) and `<?php phpinfo() ?>` (for the web server).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One from the PHP folder is for Command Line interaction, the other is for Apache itself (Web browser).

I use the CLI for my IDE (netbeans).

Comment: @JDelage Interacting with the PHP CLI.