# WAMP openssl module will not start

Tags: php, openssl

I have WAMPServer 3.1.8 installed with PHP 7.3.4. I am trying to convert my current site (using PHP 5.6 to PHP 7.3.4).

I am using CodeIgniter on my current site, and after downloading and installing the WAMP PHP extension for 7.3.4 I get the following message:

> An Error Was Encountered
>   Encryption: Unable to find an available encryption driver.

This error is due to the fact that the openssl driver is not installed (since it searches for mcrypt or openssl, and mcrypt is not in php 7.3 anymore).

So I go to my php.ini file, change the extension_dir to :

```
extension_dir = "ext"
```

and uncomment the line with openssl:

```
extension=openssl
```

I then restart all services in WAMP, after reloading the page (and showing phpinfo();) it still shows me (under the Phar part):

> OpenSSL support   disabled (install ext/openssl)

If i do the exact same steps but change PHP to 7.0.4, it works with openssl enabled.

Why is this not working for PHP 7.3.4 ?

Comment: multiple php.ini files? Just throwing something out there but I know Mamp has it, not sure about Wamp...

Comment: I can only see one .ini file in D:\wamp\bin\php\php7.3.4\php.ini

Comment: can this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/22771081/11118128 just trying to help you find a solution

Comment: Thanks for the repsonse! Unfortunately i already tried that solution to no avail